# Is there a way to see the cost index of facilities out of game?

Tags: eve-online

Is there a way to see the cost index of facilities out of game? I can't find any reference to it in the API documentation and I can't find a tab for it in EVEMon.

Comment: Yes it is possible, as Eve ISK Per Hour import indexes to calculate build costs. Where is it located however, i don't know, but i'm sure you won't find it in EVEMon, because EVEMon was made to display informations related to you character. I would suggest taking a look at CREST api, though. I'll write an answer if i find those information location.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some APIs: http://api.eve-industry.org/

Here's a handy map: [link](https://maps.eveeye.com/map.asp?map=10000042&theme=black&type=3&preset=p19&shape=cirsq&ns=1&outline=sec&ow=0.75&line=sec&lw=0.5&lbl=sec&ylbl=imgsov&side=sta&grad=none&sct=c1&fill=sov&fo=0.2&m=0.8,0,0,0.8,443.0,103.5)